# RTK Query credentials is [Object: null prototype]

Tags: cookies, credentials, rtk-query

When I send a request to the server, on server I get an error that cookies = [Object: null prototype].

**appAPI code**

```
...
export const appAPI = createApi({
  reducerPath: "appAPI",
  baseQuery  : fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl       : process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
```

**credentials   : "include"**,

```
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
        headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`);
        // headers.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
      }
      headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://localhost:3000");
      headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      return headers;
    },
  }),
...
```

**Inside the index.js file cors configuration looks like this**

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: ["http://localhost:3000"]}));
```

Comment: Please give the full error message, not your interpretation of it. The title says "credentials", the question says "headers". This is very conflicting.
Also, if the server appears on the server, maybe give more server code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send a response with JSON. Just res.json({message: "Everything OK"}) I resolve the same issue with that.